# Responsive wrapper div for image slider

Tags: html, css

So, I tried to a a responsive image slider using HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery. I have created the slider but it is not responsive. May be because the parent wrapper of the slider is not responsive. When I tried to make the parent wrapper div as responsive, either all the images inside the slider gets displayed or images are distorted(when height is assigned to parent wrapper div). We cannot remove `overflow:hidden` form parent div as it is the only property using which all images are prevented from displaying at once. Here is my fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/j6srLw9h/)
Here is my HTML for it

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="images">
        <img src="image1.jpg">
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <img src="image3.jpg">
        <img src="image4.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS for the same

```
#slider-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#slider-wrapper .images {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#slider-wrapper .images img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've tried to cut down my code to basic level so that only the parent div that needs to be responsive is mentioned along with images div inside it. What I want to achieve is make only the first image visible to it's current width and height as auto(to make sure the image is responsive) and rest all images to be hidden. I did jQuery to slide through images. Thank you :) cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified you code in order to display images one beside anothers using `display:inline-block` on them and `white-space:nowrap` on the container.

Please look at [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/j6srLw9h/1/).

```
#slider-wrapper{
    ....
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#slider-wrapper .images img{
    ....
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The rule `display:inline-block` is used to tell browser:

"*These items are to be treaten as block elements (so they can have height and width, for example) but in the meantime must be considered also as inline ones (so they are not stacked one below others but one beside others, as they would be "words")*".

In order to be placed one beside others, **is necessary that container would be enough wide to accomodate this long content** (otherwise elements would go on next rows like words in a long text). You have a fixed width container, and so you must tell browser:

"*don't wrap lines on white spaces, ignore them and place all elements on the same line*"

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what does white-space: nowrap does?

Comment: @LuckyAli I edited my answer to integrate desired explanation