# How to make a REAL responsive image slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, opencart

Here I have 'responsive image slider'on my site but as you can see, these images are not really feet well, sometimes it's bigger as in expected to be, sometimes cutted.
How can I fix this problem do I need special picture sizes for this like 4240x2600 ?

At diffrent screen resolutions it looks diffrent and odd

site -  hicandy.ru (sorry can't add more than 2 links) 
 it was built on OpenCart and slider uses 'Revolution Slider'

expamples 
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtHgN.jpg) 
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vonYQ.jpg)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819610/responsive-wrapper-div-for-image-slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819610/responsive-wrapper-div-for-image-slider)
Please have a look.

Comment: could you show your html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different options:

1. [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for display a different layout for your image slider which will be applied based on your browser size window.
2. Percentage base layout, [example](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi) (`width: 20%;`).
3. A combination of both plus JavaScript for example http://bxslider.com